# TeXMaker not quick building:Mac with latest updates texmaker, mactex

Tags: texmaker, mac, editors

Background:

Mac 10.13.X

Latest TeXMaker, MacTeX as of today 12/28/2017

side note: Previously have working before (factory reset of Mac)

I had update the "untitled.tex" file to output "hello world 2" but the TeXMaker only shows the previously compiled document "hello world".
Problem is I press the quick build function and the PDF does not update.

[image: previous compile]
[image: preferences pane]

```
LOG FILE :
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.12.26) 26 DEC 2017 13:04
entering extended mode
restricted \write18 enabled.
%&-line parsing enabled.
**Untitled.tex
(./Untitled.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.10> and hyphenation patterns for 22 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(./Untitled.aux)
\openout1 = `Untitled.aux'.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 2.
[1
{/usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (.
/Untitled.aux) )
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
201 strings out of 494437
2197 string characters out of 6166644
49119 words of memory out of 5000000
3632 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
319 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
23i,4n,17p,132b,107s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
</usr/local/texlive/2017basic/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/ams
fonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on Untitled.pdf (1 page, 11423 bytes).
PDF statistics:
12 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
7 compressed objects within 1 object stream
0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer was in the preferences. The new values are here: [image]

Default `/usr/texbin`
Fix `/Library/TeX/texbin`